# Is there a way to have 2 groups of columns 50% each in a CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with 6 columns, but what I would like is to have 2 groups of 3, where each 3 takes up 50% of the width, but each group is "left aligned".

So if I have something like:

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.cell {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cell2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="cell">Label 1</div>
  <div class="cell">60</div>
  <div class="cell">44</div>
  <div class="cell2">Label 2 (xxxx)</div>
  <div class="cell2">80</div>
  <div class="cell2">11</div>
</div>
```

Can also see [in this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/B8JOMHhUf3umy5YY?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

This will give me:

[image]

But I would like:

[image]

So each "group" (group 1 being the 1st 3 columns, group 2 being the last 3) has cells of `min-content` so they will grow as needed within their 50% width.

This is a simple example, in my real the number of `divs` is a list in an Angular component with an `*ngFor` in the markup, so I don't know the total divs in advance (I do know they are always in groups of 3 cells)

Is this possible with a **single grid**?

### Update 1

In trying to make my example simple (compared to in my app), I think I over simplified (my mistake).

It is a **table** I wish to show, so it may have many rows, so this does mean the solutions below that use the nested divs won't quite layout correct when there are more than 1 row with labels of different widths.

So if I have (from one of the solutions below):

```
 <div id="parent">
  <!-- first row -->
  <div class="cell cell1">
    <div>Label 1</div>
    <div>60</div>
    <div>44</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
    <div>Label 2 (xxxx)</div>
    <div>80</div>
    <div>11</div>
  </div>

  <!-- second row -->
  <div class="cell cell1">
    <div>Label3 xxx</div>
    <div>60</div>
    <div>44</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell1">
    <div>Label4 1xxx</div>
    <div>60</div>
    <div>44</div>
  </div>
</div>

#parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem; 
}

.cell1{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cell2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

We can see the columns won't be aligned (as in a table):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A mix of grid and flex is also a good solution.

```css
#parent {
  width:100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.cell-left, .cell-right {
  width:100%;
}

.cell-left {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.cell-right {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="flex cell-left">
    <div class="cell">Label 1</div>
    <div class="cell">60</div>
    <div class="cell">44</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="flex cell-right">
    <div class="cell2">Label 2 (xxxx)</div>
    <div class="cell2">80</div>      
    <div class="cell2">11</div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `minmax()` function:

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / repeat(2, max-content max-content minmax(25%, 1fr));
}

/* For example only */
.cell { background-color: yellow; box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #000; }
.cell:nth-child(6n+4),
.cell:nth-child(6n+5) { background-color: lightblue; }
.cell:nth-child(3n) { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="cell">Label 1</div>
  <div class="cell">60</div>
  <div class="cell">44</div>
  
  <div class="cell">Label 2 (xxxx)</div>
  <div class="cell">80</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  
  <div class="cell">Label 3 (xxxx)</div>
  <div class="cell">60</div>
  <div class="cell">44</div>
  
  <div class="cell">Label 4</div>
  <div class="cell">80</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close. The only problem I have is say `Label 1` is longer ie `Label 1xxxxxxx xxxxxxx zzzz xxxxxxxx x zzzzz` the 1st columns becomes more than 50%, and pushes the second one across. I would like the 1st column to always be a max of 50% (and I can deal with the overflow of the label using for example `text-overflow: ellipsis`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid with two columns, where each column contains a flexbox with 3 elements.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem; //if needed
}

.cell1{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cell2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="cell cell1">
      <div>Label 1</div>
      <div>60</div>
      <div>44</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
      <div>Label 2 (xxxx)</div>
      <div>80</div>
      <div>11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't need the top level grid, you can achieve the same effect with 2 nested flexbox. note flex basis of 0 on the two flex items to make them the same size.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  gap: 1rem; //if needed
}

.cell1{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cell2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="cell cell1">
      <div>Label 1</div>
      <div>60</div>
      <div>44</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell2">
      <div>Label 2 (xxxx)</div>
      <div>80</div>
      <div>11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: start;
}
.child-row{

display:flex;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 
  <div class="child-row">
  <div>first--->  1.1</div>
  <div>content 1.2</div>            
  <div>content 1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-row">
  <div>content 1.1</div>
  <div>content 1.2</div>
  <div>content 1.3</div>
  </div>

 <div class="child-row">
 <div>second--->  2.1</div>
 <div>content 2.2</div>    
 <div>content 2.3</div>
 </div>
  <div class="child-row">
  <div>content 2.1</div>
  <div>content 2.2</div>
  <div>content 2.3</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="child-row">
  <div>third--->  3.1</div>
  <div>content 3.2</div>    
  <div>content 3.3</div>   
  </div>
  <div class="child-row">
  <div>content 3.1</div>
  <div>content 3.2</div>
  <div>content 3.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```